# A Device Driver Has Pool Error

Tags: c, windows, device-driver, bsod

I'm writing a windows device driver. The driver is very simple. It does nothing fancy. I'm just trying to get familiar with the windows driver development.

In my driver I'm allocating some memory from `NonPagedPool`, but have a very strange error.

Here goes my code segment:

```
pMyNode = (PMY_NODE)ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, sizeof(MY_NODE), 'TEST');
if (pMyNode == NULL){
    DbgPrint("Not Enough Memory\n");
}
else{
    // Do Some Stuffs and free memory
}
```

The corresponding assembly code(from IDA Pro Disassembler) is:

```
call ds:__imp__ExAllocatePoolWithTag
mov [ebp+pMyNode], eax
cmp [ebp+pMyNode], 0
jnz  SOME_OFFSET
call _DbgPrint

SOME_OFFSET:
.........
.........
```

This code segment goes into the handler function of `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine`. So every time a new process is created, this code segment gets executed. Now if I run the driver for a long time, I get `BSoD` error suddenly. And `WinDbg` triggers the instruction `mov [ebp+pMyNode], eax` as the faulting instruction. This line actually assigns the return value of `ExAllocatePoolWithTag` to `pMyNode` pointer. I don't understand howcome this might be a faulty instruction.

The error message in `BSoD` screen is `A Device Driver Has Pool`. Check the `WinDbg` log below:

```
DRIVER_CORRUPTED_EXPOOL (c5)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is
caused by drivers that have corrupted the system pool.  Run the driver
verifier against any new (or suspect) drivers, and if that doesn't turn up
the culprit, then use gflags to enable special pool.
Arguments:
Arg1: e252a000, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000d, IRQL
Arg3: 00000001, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
Arg4: 8054baee, address which referenced memory
```

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: updated the question with some WinDbg log information.

Comment: So according to the memory dump, 0x8054baee is the address of your mov instruction?  I'm puzzled as to why the IRQL is 13, since the notification routine should be run at PASSIVE_LEVEL.  My best guess is that the failure is actually occurring inside the call to ExAllocatePoolWithTag, and that the cause is indeed that the system pool has become corrupted - unfortunately that could be happening anywhere in your driver, or someone else's, for that matter.

Comment: Is this 32-bit or 64-bit Windows?  Perhaps you could try a call to KeGetCurrentIrql before calling ExAllocatePoolWithTag to verify the IRQL?

Comment: @HarryJohnston It is a 32-bit system. I can check the IRQL before calling it. Will update on that. Also you are right. The failure occurs inside ExAllocatePoolWithTag. I checked the address which referenced the memory and found out its inside ExAllocatePoolWithTag. So how can I corrupt the system pool? I mean what type of operation can corrupt the system pool?

Comment: The system pool can only become corrupted if a device driver (probably but not necessarily yours) writes to a memory location it shouldn't.  For example, by writing past the end of a buffer you've allocated.  On a 32-bit system, [according to this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/doronh/archive/2010/02/02/what-is-irql.aspx), IRQL 13 is used by device interrupts.  Perhaps a device interrupt is occurring during the call to ExAllocatePoolWithTag?  That might mean that the real problem is in the device interrupt routine, but I'm not familiar enough with the kernel to be sure whether that idea makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. Lets just assume everything in my driver is okay, no buffer overflow, nothing. Still if I make a call to ExAllocatePoolWithTag and in the meantime a device interrupt raises the IRQL level, is it going to cause a problem with the memory allocation?

Comment: No, unless there is a bug in one of the device drivers (or elsewhere in the kernel) there shouldn't be a problem.